# Android Activity to Fragment - Possible without massive changes?

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-activity

I've finished one of my new games and I think it would be 10x better with some kind of Facebook integration. I'm new to the facebook sdk and I can see that it utilises fragments, which I'm not overly familiar with (yet)... Before I go off and completely break my game, can I easily convert my current Activities into Fragments without effecting current layouts, or creating a stupid amount of work for myself? Thanks!

Comment: If you want the same behavior and layout as now, not too difficult.  It becomes time consuming when you want to make it act like fragments-  have multiple independent on screen entities that may need to communicate.

Comment: No. Ideally I'd like to keep everything as-is as of right now. And just create the main fragment that will inflate all of the others. I have multiple activities, each one complete and finished. The only thing I'd do is add a facebook share button to the main game activity. Is it just a case of changing "extends Activity" to "extends Fragment" and then add unimplemented methods? I'm reluctant to make many code changes without knowing first :)

Comment: A little more than that.  You make your Activity extend FragmentActivity.  Then you can add fragments inside the xml of that activity-  or you can choose not to do so.  Fragments and non-fragment UI elements can work together, so long as you don't ever want to page out the non-fragment elements.  If you do, then you need to move all the stuff in your curent activity into a Fragment class, implement onCreateView (replaces onCreate), and have a new FragmentActivity that starts you up, generally by placing you into a frame layout.  But it should just be a few hours work, at most.

Comment: I can manage a few hours. Thanks for your help Gabe! Much appreciated.